# How to expand the width of navigation bar in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Is it possible to expand the width of navigation bar in iPhone?

Comment: the width is the full width of the screen. how can you expand it further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are asking for...?  I'm guessing you mean it's height, not it's width.  The width should expand to cover the entire x-direction (320px in portrait, 480px in landscape)

repost:
[Change UINavigationBar Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894985/iphone-sdk-change-navigation-bar-height)