# How to change height of UINavigationbar in ios5

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

After i do many test for change height of uinavigationbar. It seems that there are no effective ways can do that.  self.navigationController.navigationBar.transform=CGAFFINE is not so good, It will also expand title and barbutton item. Is there any idea to do that.
Very appreciated you help!

Answer (score 2):

you can't change the height of navigation bar..

you can only change its `width`

Comment: Yep, iOS 5 really takes away any control of the nav bar, and even makes it a lot harder to override it with your own.

Comment: So,That's meant UINavigationBar can not be feel free to change according to the requirements. It's too limited to develop customize App

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894985/iphone-sdk-change-navigation-bar-height .. check the third answer involving category on the above link

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds.size.width, 94.0f);
```