# Change UINavigationBar background image and make the UINavigationBar to scale

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

What is the easiest way to change UINavigationBar background image and make the main UINavigationBar to scale to the background image size?

I designed a navigation bar that is not the size of my table view controller navigation bar, and now I imported the image to Xcode and I want to do something like:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BG.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

but that does not work, anyway I think that this way I will have a problem with the height since my designed nav is bigger.

How can I do this please?

Comment: @ZuzooVn nope i didnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to not do that, there are some hacks than you can do, for example hide navigation bar and create a personalized bar with the height you want.

Check this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7533098/4559321

I recommend to change your design to fit with the standard UINavigationBar and you will save lot of work.