# can't customize navigationbar frame in iOS 10?

Tags: ios, ios10, navigationbar, xcode8

I customized the navigation bar frame(y position) so it shows on the bottom in iOS 9.x with code like:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 320-32, oldRect.size.width, oldRect.size.height);
```

but it stops working in iOS 10. got something like the screenshot.the top part is covered too. Any idea how to fix this?[image]

Comment: Use this: [self.navigationController.navigationBar layoutIfNeeded]; and try

Comment: You should be doing this way http://stackoverflow.com/a/31054978/790842

Comment: I don't need to change the height of the navgation bar,  need to change the y position of the navgation bar.[self.navigationController.navigationBar layoutIfNeeded]; also doesn't seem to work, it worked in iOS 9.x but not in iOS 10.