# how to change the default height of navigation bar in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uinavigationbar

I have a question: When I am trying to change the default height of navigation bar it is not possible for me to change it. How to change that height?

Comment: This is duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/892905/change-iphone-navigation-bars-height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not change the height of navigation bar but you can make custom navigation bar with View and Images for look same as Navigation bar.