# iOS 6.0 + Auto Layout + navigation bar in landscape mode + height is reduced

Tags: ios

I am using iOS 6.0 and Auto Layout in my project.

In this, I am using NavigationViewcontroller. The problem is when I am rotating the device to landscape mode, the navigation bar height is reduced. How to keep the same height of the navigation bar as in portrait mode as for landscape mode also?

Comment: @Ashok its by default height of navigation controller in landscape mode

Answer (score 0):

You can't change it, you should to google before putting question.

Making the navigation bar taller is a violation of Apple Human Interface Guidelines, and your application may be rejected from the App Store because of it.Read this

[Change iPhone navigation bar's height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892905/change-iphone-navigation-bars-height)

Comment: @Hi searched in google but I did not the correct answer. But I know i will get the answer surely in StackOverFlow. Thats why I have posted here. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @Ashok -why u want to change the default height of uinavigation bar

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code...

This will work for the Custom UINavigation Bar , I'm not sure about your req.

```
   CGFloat navBarHeight = [navBar sizeThatFits:self.bounds.size].height;

    // Resizing navigationBar
    navBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, navBarHeight);
```